# what happends with the memory of the objects used in NSMutableDictionary when releasing the array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release, nsmutabledictionary, autorelease

I'm curious what happens with the memory of the objects that I push with `[array addObject:object]` when I use `[array release]`

- does addObject copy the pointers?
- do I have to retain the objects ?
- do I have to make a for and release each object then the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
[array addObject:object]
```

`array` retains `object`, thereby incrementing its retain count.

Later, when `array` is sent the message `dealloc`, it calls `release` on `object`.

To avoid memory leaks, you may have to release `object` after you add it to the `array`, e.g.

```
NSObject *object = [[NSObject] alloc] init];
[array addObject:object];
[object release];
```

Make sure you review the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) to be certain that you are not over or under releasing `object`.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to this one!

Comment: "To avoid memory leaks, you should release object after you add it to the array..." Um, no. The OP never specified how he obtained the reference. He should follow the memory management guidelines here just as he would anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

addObject does a retain on that object you add. And when you release the array it automatically calls release on all objects it holds.

Answer (score 1):

When you do [array addObject: object], the array is retaining the object that is inserted into the array.  To avoid memory leaks, don't forget to release the original object that was inserted, or else the object being inserted into the array will have a retain count of 2 instead of 1:

```
SomeClassObject *obj = [[SomeClassObject alloc] init];
[array addObject:obj];
[obj release];
```

Since the array owns the objects that are inside of the array (holds a pointer to that object and did a retain as explained previously), when you release the array, the array knows to release any objects that are inside of it.  The work is done for you!

Answer (score 0):

NSArrays retain added objects, so you don't have to add extra retains yourself, and can just release the array when done.